# What's the equivalent of Verilog tilde operator "~" in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

In Verilog and c-language, I can easy negate a vector by using the tilde operator. Example:

```
// Verilog
module try;
wire [7:0] a = 8'b1111_0000;
reg  [7:0] b;

initial begin
    b = ~a;
    // b = 8'b0000_1111;
end

endmodule
```

How would I do that same in VHDL?

```
-- VHDL
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity design is
end entity;

architecture rtl of design is
    a: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := X"0F";
    b: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    b <= ?negate? a;
    -- result: b = X"F0"
end architecture;
```

Comment: In ISO/IEC 9899 C ~ is bitwise complementation where integer types in C or Verilog reveal underlying types with bits. Negation in VHDL is performed on scalar or element types representing signed numbers using the unary operator "-". Logical complementation  in VHDL  for types representing Booleans or bits including array types uses the "not" logical operator.

Comment: VHDL types integer and real are scalar numeric types without logical operations - they don't have 'bits' unlike -2008 fixed_pkg/fixed_generic_pkg and float_pkg/float_generic_pkg with std_ulogic elements('bits') which have "not" operators. This comes from Ada which follows mathematical definition not underlying machine types - Ada or VHDL can run on machines with decimal based ALUs given sufficient support for scalar minimum value ranges.

Answer (score 4):

The `not` operator:

```
b <= not a;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity testbench is
end entity;

architecture rtl of testbench is
begin

process
    variable a :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := X"F0";
    variable b :std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
    b := not a;
    report "a:" & to_hstring(a);
    report "b:" & to_hstring(b);
    wait;
end process;
end architecture;
```

```
C:\> ghdl.exe -a --std=08 --ieee=synopsys --work=work ./testit.vhd
C:\> ghdl.exe --elab-run --std=08 testbench --ieee-asserts=disable
./testit.vhd:17:5:@0ms:(report note): a:F0
./testit.vhd:18:5:@0ms:(report note): b:0F
```